# c++ queue.push() error, why I cannot push value into a queue

Tags: queue, push

q.push() can be done successfully for the first time. But it will go wrong for the second.  The debugger(eclipse) will open new_allocator.h file and point to the lines of code below" // 402. wrong new expression in [some_] allocator::construct".

Thanks for your help.

The code is simple as follows:

```
    struct argType{
        char *name;
        std::queue<char *> q;//each argType has a queue for round robin
    } *argTypeDB;

    int main() {
        char *name = "na";

        char *a = "122,3,4,5,32,,21;";
        argTypeDB = (struct argType *)malloc(sizeof(struct argType));
        argTypeDB[0].name = name;
        for(int i = 0; i< 5; i++){
            argTypeDB[0].q.push(a);
            printf("%d\n", i);
        }

        free(argTypeDB);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using malloc to alloc argTypeDB instead of using the constructor for argType.
This is wrong because queue is not actually constructed, its only has space allocated for it.

```
argTypeDB = new argType();

...

delete argTypeDB;
```